# gdal_calc.py: error: the following arguments are required: --outfile

Tags: error, gdal-calc

I'm trying to perform an operation using gdal calculator:

```
90*logical_and(A==111, B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)
```

but I get the following error:

```
gdal_calc.py: error: the following arguments are required: --outfile
```

Do you know what it means?

**COMMAND IN GDAL RASTER CALCULATOR**

input raster A: Uso_suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off (EPSG: 32632, float 32); input raster B: gruppi_idro_reclass_dimension (EPSG: 32632, 8 byte);

```
gdal_calc.bat --calc "gdal_calc.bat --calc "90*logical_and(A==111,B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\data\orto\3band.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\data\orto\3band.tif --B_band 2 -C C:\data\orto\3band.tif --C_band 3 --outfile C:/Temp/processing_xIueLp/c3ead72b992c4f9baac3f260b69082c2/OUTPUT.tif" --format GTiff --type Byte -A "Uso suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off" --A_band 1 --B "C:\\Users\\Anto\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Progetto ROMA\\DATI\\Dati GIS\\Acqua\\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif" --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif
```

output raster: float 32

**RESULT**

> gdal_calc.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
> suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off --A_band 1 --B
> C:\Users\Anto\OneDrive\Desktop\Progetto ROMA\DATI\Dati
> GIS\Acqua\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif --B_band 1 --outfile
> C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif

---

**COMMAND IN GDAL RASTER CALCULATOR**

```
input raster A: Uso_suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off (EPSG: 32632, float 32); input raster B: gruppi_idro_reclass_dimension (EPSG: 32632, 8 byte);

gdal_calc.bat --calc "gdal_calc.bat --calc "90*logical_and(A==111,B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\data\orto\3band.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\data\orto\3band.tif --B_band 2 -C C:\data\orto\3band.tif --C_band 3 --outfile C:/Temp/processing_xIueLp/c3ead72b992c4f9baac3f260b69082c2/OUTPUT.tif" --format GTiff --type Byte -A "Uso suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off" --A_band 1 --B "C:\\Users\\Anto\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Progetto ROMA\\DATI\\Dati GIS\\Acqua\\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif" --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif

output raster: float 32
```

**RESULT**

```
gdal_calc.py: error: unrecognized arguments: suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off --A_band 1 --B C:\\Users\\Anto\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Progetto ROMA\\DATI\\Dati GIS\\Acqua\\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif
```

Comment: In Qgis 3.16.11

Comment: Do you use command line or a tool in QGIS?

Comment: Hi Kadir, I use the GDAL calculator tool in Qgis

Comment: Do you mean "GDAL > Raster miscalleneous > Raster calculator"?

Comment: This is the operation I entered:

90*logical_and(A==111, B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)

Comment: Yes, GDAL > Raster miscalleneous > Raster calculator

Comment: Does it work with the default settings and algorithm? Defaults seem to generate a GDAL command like `gdal_calc.bat --calc "A*2" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\test\test.tif --A_band 1 --outfile C:/Temp/processing_xIueLp/5f627158b03a458ebec6fffa42673d7f/OUTPUT.tif`

Comment: What is your raster source? I managed get the same error by using a WMS layer as a source. Could you add the generated GDAL command into your question? You can read the meaning of parameters from https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me with a normal 8-bit RGB raster file.
The generated GDAL command in this case is

```
gdal_calc.bat --calc "90*logical_and(A==111, B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\data\orto\3band.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\data\orto\3band.tif --B_band 2 -C C:\data\orto\3band.tif --C_band 3 --outfile C:/Temp/processing_xIueLp/c3ead72b992c4f9baac3f260b69082c2/OUTPUT.tif
```

Comment: Hi User 30184, thank you for your help.
I inserted two rasters (A=land use code 111,112 etc) and B = hydrological groups = 3 or 4). The rasters are in the same projection and same cell size, they differ only because the first one is float32 while the second one is 8 bytes. 
In GDAL commands I put float32 as output format.

Comment: I tried with the formula you entered, but it gives me the following error (with both float32 and byte output) :

gdal_calc.py: error: unrecognized arguments: soil_like hydro groups reclass_off --A_band 1 -B C:\Users\\Anto\OneDrive\Desktop\Project ROMA\\Data GIS\Acqua\Groups Hydro_reclass. tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif

Comment: Please add your exact command to your question. And use file names which do not have spaces.

Comment: input raster A: Uso_suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off (EPSG: 32632; float 32);
input raster B: gruppi_idro_reclass_dimension (EPSG: 32632; 8 byte);

Comment: gdal_calc.bat --calc "gdal_calc.bat --calc "90*logical_and(A==111,B==3) + 92*logical_and(A==111, B==4) + 81*logical_and(A==112, B==3) + 86*logical_and(A==112, B==4)"

Comment: --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\data\orto\3band.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\data\orto\3band.tif --B_band 2 -C C:\data\orto\3band.tif --C_band 3 --outfile C:/Temp/processing_xIueLp/c3ead72b992c4f9baac3f260b69082c2/OUTPUT.tif" --format GTiff --type Byte -A "Uso suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off" --A_band 1 --B "C:\\Users\\Anto\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Progetto ROMA\\DATI\\Dati GIS\\Acqua\\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif" --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif

Comment: output raster: float 32

Comment: gdal_calc.py: error: unrecognized arguments: suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off --A_band 1 --B C:\\Users\\Anto\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Progetto ROMA\\DATI\\Dati GIS\\Acqua\\Gruppi_idro_reclass.tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/Anto/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_zxLIka/29c0cbd5ca6547f995f39f24fa301993/OUTPUT.tif

Comment: Here, I hope it can be understood. Thanks @user30184

Comment: Please add all that info into your question, it is hard for the readers to find the information from the comments. But it is obvious that spaces are clipping the command. `Uso suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off` gets cut into parts `Uso` and `suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off`, therefore error `unrecognized arguments: suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off`. And don't copy the names of my files into your command.

Comment: Ok @user30184 I will copy everything in the question, sorry but it's my first time using this forum.

Comment: Could you please enter the operation I need to put in without your information? Thanks

Comment: Remove everything that refers to my test image "3band.tif", like `-A C:\data\orto\3band.tif`. But if you just rename your file so that it does not contains space in the name it should work fine with QGIS. If you want to use gdal_calc directly follow the examples in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html.

Comment: Ok I'm trying it using the guide in gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html

Comment: I'm still trying, even following the instructions in the manual and in some online tutorials, but I keep getting the following error:

 **gdal_calc.py: error: the following arguments are required: --outfile**

yet the commands I set are the same of some tutorials, that is in my case:

**gdal_calc.py  -A Uso_suolo_like_gruppi_idro_reclass_off.tif  -B gruppi_idro_reclass_dimension.tif –-outfile= OUTPUT.tif -–calc="....."**

it's a bit frustrating! :(

Comment: here is the example on the manual, it seems that the output file can be called whatever you want

**gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="(A+B)/2"**

Comment: I finally found the solution, much simpler, I simply entered the formula of calculation without any other commands and it came!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, much simpler, I simply entered the formula without any other commands and it came!

[image]

Comment: **Thanks to everyone!**